# unable to register (com.google.iid error 1005.)

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I'm attempting to integrate GCM into our iOS app.
I've followed the instructions to update our project for GCM to no avail.
Everything I try to register I get:

```
Registration to GCM failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error 1005.)
```

Which GLLInstance.h say:

```
  /// Should call `startWithConfig:` before requesting token.
  kGGLInstanceIDOperationErrorCodeInvalidStart = 1005,
```

I am calling :

```
[[GCMService sharedInstance] startWithConfig:[GCMConfig defaultConfig]];
```

before registering for notifications...
There aren't any obvious errors from GCM
This IS on a device...
(just trying to eliminate the obvious)

What next steps should I try?

Answer (score 0):

As usual as soon as I post a question to SO, the answer leaps out at me.

The routine:

```
[[GCMService sharedInstance] startWithConfig:[GCMConfig defaultConfig]];
```

which I knew I was calling in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
```

right before

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

was needed in ***two*** locations... I missed that.
Once I added it just before the call:

```
[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:_gcmSenderID
                                                    scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                  options:_registrationOptions
                                                  handler:_registrationHandler];
```

in:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
```

everything started working.
Delightful...

Comment: Could you please tell me if you have to use the line `[[GCMService sharedInstance] startWithConfig:[GCMConfig defaultConfig]];` to receive simple push notifications? The documentation is not clear about this.

Comment: to receive simple push notifications via GCM, I needed to include that line in two different spots as mentioned in my answer.