# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with GCM 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to integrate GCM v3 into a cocos2d-x v3.6 project, and after a few days of getting things working with CocoaPods and Xcode, I finally was able to build the app. However, when deployed on device for testing, it crashes on calling `[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:_gcmSenderID scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM options:_registrationOptions handler:_registrationHandler]` with the error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. What gives?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvFqY.png

My configuration is as follows:

> `daffodilistic$ pod --version
>   0.39.0.beta.4
>   daffodilistic$ cat Podfile 
>   platform :ios, '8.1'
>   source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
>   target 'project-redacted iOS' do
>       pod 'Google/CloudMessaging' 
>   end 
>   target 'project-redacted Mac' do
>   end`

Comment: Here's a good starting point: http://loufranco.com/blog/understanding-exc_bad_access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to debug and resolve the exception successfully - apparently, it's caused by a `NULL` or `0x00000000` value being pointed to by the `@property(nonatomic, retain) void (^registrationHandler)` block property declared earlier on as per [Google's sample GCM v3 code for iOS](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExample/AppDelegate.m#L20). As to whether it was Xcode, iOS or cocos2d-x causing the block declaration to be dereferenced/deallocated, I'm not sure.

The solution was to move the `(^registrationHandler)` [block declaration](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExample/AppDelegate.m#L67-L82) from

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

to

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

Related SO link which was useful, but not really crucial: [unable to register (com.google.iid error 1005.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737406/unable-to-register-com-google-iid-error-1005)